# Huge data processing in Talend using tJavaFlex- Kafka streaming

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, heap-memory, talend

I am using tJavaflex component to build kafka consumer. Following is the code snippet for polling the stream to read the messages

```
// here is the main part of the component,
// a piece of code executed in the row
// loop
try {
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(context.consumer_polltime);
        if (records.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("inside break");
            break;
        };
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            i++;
            listPayload.add(record.value());        
        }
    }
    globalMap.put("ConsumerObj",consumer);  
            
} catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Consuming Msg: " + e);
            // TODO: handle exception
            //consumer.close();
} finally {
  consumer.close();
}

row21.payload= String.valueOf(listPayload);
globalMap.put("MsgCount",i);
```

The output of this component is redirected to tExtractJsonfields as my stream contains json messages

The issue with the above code is that as the number of messages increases, heap space is completely occupied by the **ArrayList** and I am getting the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

How can I push messages after every poll to the next step for processing, clear the list and continue the loop to read further messages?

Comment: Why not just increase your heap size?

Comment: Note: `String.valueOf` on a list of objects wouldn't be JSON

Comment: No, messages can go upto 5Million records i.e., upto 2GB at peak times. Already tested 1.5Million records with 5GB heap space according to my organization's maximum allotment. It failed. The built in talend component tKafkaInput reads 5000messages and pushes it to next component before reading next 5000 messages. But due to some version compatibility issues cannot use it. I want to replicate the same functionality in my code too.

Comment: Okay, well, I don't know Talend, but you can configure KafkaConsumer `max.poll.records` and you can break your loop on `listPayload.size()` exceeding some value rather than let it grow indefinitely

Comment: I tried placing this code ```row21.payload= String.valueOf(listPayload);``` after for loop which reads about 50 messages for every loop(poll) and then goes back to while loop for another poll and placed one more code to clear the list. But the issue is that the data only gets propagated to next component after the previous component is completed. So I am just getting the last 50 messages. I need a way to synchronously propagate data as well as read it

Comment: Well, we don't know what `row21` or `globalMap` objects actually are, so difficult to help with that. Please show a [mcve] of all code and describe how things "get propagated"